# DRF lowercase header key

Tags: ember.js, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to use lowercase HTTP header key "content-type" with django rest framework parsers?

HTTP headers are case insensitive, but it doesn't seem to work with DRF 3.3.2. My frontend (emberjs) sends request with lowercase header name by [ember-network](https://github.com/tomdale/ember-network)(Fetch API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. But ember-network or Fetch API doesn't return success and error callback.

Instead:

```
fetch(url, {/options/}).then(
 (success) => {
  //
 },
 (error) => {
 //
 });
```

use:

```
fetch(url, {/options/}).then(
  (response) => {
       if (response.status >= 400) {
         //error
       } else {
         //success
       }
  }
);
```

Note `response.json() returns a promise`, my code is:

```
function request(url, type, data){
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let headers = {...};
    let credentials = 'include';
    fetch(url, {
          method: type,
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: headers,
          credentials: credentials
        }).then((response) => {
          response.json().then(
            (json) => {
               if (response.status >= 400) {
                 reject(json);
               } else {
                 resolve(json);
               }
            })
        });
}
```